# How do you download *all* pipeline resources in a job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The `deployment` job automatically downloads all the pipeline resources.  However, standard `job` does not.  I tried to use `- download: current`, but that does not download the pipeline resources.

The reason I want to do this is to simulate a deployment for GitOps.  The simulation will include a step that does a `git diff` that shows the differences for review.

However, I don't see an `all` or `*` option in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#download

My current workaround is to do a `deployment` to a "Temp" environment prior to the real `deployment`.

UPDATE:
Here's an example of what I have tried

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: auth
      project: myproj
      source: auth CI
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master
...
    jobs:
      - job: diagnostics
        displayName: Job Diagnostics
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          # - download: 
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
            inputs:
              path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
          - bash: |
              env | sort
            displayName: Display environment variables
          - bash: |
              pwd
            displayName: Present working directory
          - bash: |
              find $(Pipeline.Workspace) -type f -print
            displayName: Display files
```

UPDATE:
Another approach I was mulling is to create a pipeline that creates another pipeline.  That way the list of pipeline resources does not need to be Azure Pipeline YAML, it could be a CSV or a simplified YAML that I transform in which case I can generate

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipelineAlias1
      project: myproj
      source: auth CI
      branch: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master

    - pipeline: pipelineAlias2
      project: myproj
      source: auth CI
      branch: master
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master
...
job:
  steps:
   - download: pipelineAlias1
   - download: pipelineAlias2
```

and then set that up as another Azure pipeline to execute when updated.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you download *all* pipeline resources in a job?

Indeed, this is a known issue about using the **download** keyword to download the Pipeline Artifacts.

You could track this issue from below ticket:

[Artifacts do not download on multi stage yaml build using DownloadPipelineArtifactV2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11267)

To resolve this issue, please try to use the [DownloadPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) task instead of the **download** keyword:

```
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2

    displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
    inputs:
      path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

**Update:**

I have noticed your yml file, it seems you do not add build job in your pipeline. The task [DownloadPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) is used to:

> download **pipeline artifacts from earlier stages in this pipeline**,
>   or from another pipeline

So, we need to add stage to build the pipeline to generate the artifact, otherwise, no pipeline artifacts were downloaded.

Check my test YAML file:

```
variables:
  ArtifactName: drop

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
     name: MyPrivateAgent
    steps:
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\LibmanTest'
          targetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: LibmanTest'
        inputs:
          ArtifactName: $(ArtifactName)


- stage: Dev
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Dev
    displayName: Dev
    pool:
     name: MyPrivateAgent
    steps:
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestSample'
          targetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: TestSample'
        inputs:
          ArtifactName: $(ArtifactName)


- stage: Deployment
  dependsOn: Dev  
  pool:
    name: MyPrivateAgent
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deployment
    displayName: DeployA
    environment: 7-1-0
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2

            displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact'
            inputs:
              path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

As you can see, I use two stages `Build` and `Dev` to copy the project `LibmanTest` and `TestSample` as artifact, then use the task DownloadPipelineArtifact to download those two artifacts.

The test result:

[image]

**Update2:**

> your example still does not show resources.pripelines

So, now you want to download the artifact from other pipelines, you need not use the default configuration for the task DownloadPipelineArtifact:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: xxx
      project: MyTestProject
      source: xxx
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - master

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deployment
    displayName: DeployA
    environment: 7-1-0
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifact For Test'
            inputs:
              buildType: specific
              project: MyTestProject
              definition: 13
```

The test result:

[image]

Besides, you could check the configuration from the classic editor, then get the YAML file:

[image]

Hope this hellps.

Comment: This does not work.  No pipeline artifacts were downloaded

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, As test on my side, it works fine, please check my update answer with detailed info, would you please check if it helps you?

Comment: Hi your example still does not show `resources.pripelines`

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, you said you use the `- download: current`, so I download it from current pipeline, but now you want to download the artifact from other pipeline. So, you need to configure task DownloadPipelineArtifact, not use the default. I will update my answer with a detailed a sample.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, Updated the answer again, please check if it resolved your question.

Comment: Nope the last one just downloads a specific one, which means I would have to repeat my list of pipeline resources.  Which is what I was trying to avoid.

That being the case, I may need a pipeline to build another pipeline.

Comment: I actually want to download ALL pipeline resources basically what `deployment` does by default.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, I am afraid you can not do this, otherwise, you need create the power shell scripts to download all the ALL pipeline resources. There is no such task to download ALL pipeline resources like deployment job directly. If we want this, why not use deployment job directly? If we can simply use a task to do it directly, why does MS provide a deployment job? Too personalized needs, you need to develop your own script.

Comment: Added reason to OP